# No provisioned iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device or choose an iOS simulator as the destination

Tags: iphone, xcode4, sdk

> No provisioned iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I have profiles for my device for this app... where should I be looking to correct this? I am using XCode 6.0 while version of my iPhone is 6.0.1, may i need to update my Mac SDK to 6.0.1?

Comment: Start by looking at the device list in organizer. What does it say when your device is connected?